# How can I extract a specific Letter(s) and numbers from a text string via VBA Or excel Formula

Tags: vba, excel, user-defined-functions, data-extraction

I would like to extract a combination of text and numbers from a larger string located within a column within excel.

The constants I have to work with is that each Text string will

- either start with a A, C or S, and
- will always be 7 Characters long
- the position of he string I would like to extract varies.

For example;

> COB0012 WP0402 Electronic Payments - SME Consultancy
>   DCPY708 A850035 WP161 Configuration Manager Core General (Aman Ranjan) 
>   A614019 WP0302 SQL 2005 Upgrade Project – WFCopiesChq - Next Stage 
>   SUTP016 EPM Training T2

Output

> COB0012
>   A850035
>   SUTP016

I have knowledge of the standard Left / Right / Mid / Search functions however my data set is vary large so I would like to create something which would automate this process. (1000's of rows)

I imagine a UDF function would do the trick but my familarity with UDF's is very basic.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: What are the rules that differentiate DCPY708 from A850035?

Comment: @JeremyThompson `DCPY708` doesn't start with `A / C or S`.

Comment: @OlleSjögren The criteria is not really clear. One could easily identify the difference is that `DCPY708` starts with 4 letters instead of `A850035`'s 1 letter and a check on that condition would cover a much larger number of SKUs. I know that SUTP016 breaks the above rule, but it is generally better programming not to hardcode letters - especially if you're future proofing software.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`@Gary's Student` variant but has some difference

```
Public Function Xtractor(r As Range) As String
    Dim a, ary
    ary = Split(r.Text, " ")
    For Each a In ary
        If Len(a) = 7 And a Like "[SAC]*" Then
            Xtractor = a
            Exit Function
        End If
    Next a
End Function
```

output

[image]

Comment: Thanks Vasily, this seems to work perfectly. I understand the majority of the Macro. :) (Which is good news) For my understanding could you explain what  the purpose of [ ary = Split(r.Text, " ") ] is?

Comment: thnks @Gary'sStudent, but the logic is yours )

Comment: @SeanBailey ary is array, cell value has been split into separate words by split() function into this array, and then each word from this array has been checked by two conditions (the first char and length of the word)

Comment: Brilliant thank you both very much for your help! I have learnt something new today! :)

Comment: Hi Both, Ive recently posted a question regarding this code as a new question as I need to slightly adapt it as I have learnt a couple more rules - if you get a chance please could you have a look at it - As i figured you would have the best knowledge of how to adapt the code                                                http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30758254/slight-adaptation-of-a-user-defined-function

Answer (score 2):

Consider:

```
Public Function Xtractor(r As Range) As String
   Dim CH As String, L As Long
   ary = Split(r.Text, " ")
   For Each a In ary
      L = Len(a)
      CH = Left(a, 1)
      If L = 7 Then
         If CH = "S" Or CH = "A" Or CH = "C" Then
            Xtractor = a
            Exit Function
         End If
      End If
   Next a
   Xtractor = ""
End Function
```

[image]

Comment: Sorry I tend to disagree, checking words are 7 chars long and start with 1 of 3 letters is not a future proof method. ps no need to set  `Xtractor = ""`

Answer (score 0):

A regex will be very efficient - especially if you combine it with a variant array rather than a range.

```
Sub UseaRegex()
MsgBox StrChange("COB0012 WP0402 Electronic Payments - SME Consultancy [I would require COB0012]")
MsgBox StrChange("DCPY708 A850035 WP161 Configuration Manager Core General (Aman Ranjan)")
End Sub
```

*function*

```
Function StrChange(strIn As String) As String
Dim objRegex As Object
Set objRegex = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")
With objRegex
    .Pattern = "[ACS]\w{6}"
     If .test(strIn) Then
        StrChange = .Execute(strIn)(0)
     Else
        StrChange = "No match"
     End If
End With
End Function
```